# Preconditioning

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, computational-statistics

## Problem Statement

Let $\pi(x)$ be my target distribution and suppose $\text{Var}_\pi[X] = \Sigma$.

Suppose also that I have obtained samples $X^{1:N}\sim \pi$, computed their sample covariance matrix $\hat{\Sigma} = \text{Cov}(X^{1:N})$ and found a matrix square root $\hat{A}$ such that $\hat{\Sigma} = \hat{A}^\top \hat{A}$.

Now define $\tilde{X} = A^{-\top}X$. The paper that I am reading then says that if we define $g(x)=\nabla_x \log\pi(x)$ then
$$
\tilde{g}(\tilde{x}) = Ag(x)
$$
Is this true?

## Attempt

Using the change of variables formula we know
$$
\tilde{\pi}(\tilde{x}) = \frac{1}{|A^\top|} \cdot \pi(A^\top x)
$$
Taking the log of this
$$
\log\tilde{\pi}(\tilde{x}) = -\log\det A^\top + \log\pi(A^\top \tilde{x})
$$
Importantly the Jacobian is the transpose of the gradient in this case, so
$$
J_{\log\tilde{\pi}}(\tilde{x}) = J_{\log\pi}(x) A^\top
$$
and
$$
\tilde{g}(\tilde{x}) = A g(x)
$$